# How do big publishers edit their websites?

Tags: web-development, web-applications, web-design

I've been trying to develop a website with some success for the past few months. One question that I always have lurking at the back of my mind is whether to develop a very in-depth, powerful admin panel in favor of me just editing the code.

In a more simpler words, let's say I'm the developer for nbcnews.com. On NBC's navigation bar, there's “2020 Election,” “Coronavirus,” and “Breaking News.” The first wo are temporary events. When they will be replaced with a more relevant topic, would the news agency:

1. Adjust the contents through the administration panel?
2. Or ask the coders to change the navigation bar?

Comment: Question edited to avoid it to be closed as “This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.” There is now only one question—the one from the title.

Answer (score 1):

You need to better understand what happens when source code changes.

Let's imagine that the website has a hardcoded logotype. Recently, the marketing decided to change the logotype, and the new one is now available. The development team is asked to change it.

1. First, they need to locate where exactly the link to the logotype is coded, and where the old logotype is stored. That should be easy.
2. The new logotype needs now to be updated to the CDN. The developer performing this action needs to have a good understanding of the approach used by the site to handle static content, and how the resources are handled through the CDN. For instance, how long would it take for the new logotype to be replicated accross the globe? Should there be a manual action from the developer, or would it be done automatically?
3. Is there just one version of the logotype, or some countries have their own version, adjusted according to their culture (for instance different colors being used in different countries)? How this is handled now? How would it be handled with the new logotype?
4. How different sizes of the logotype are handled? Maybe a visitor who's using an old smartphone with a small screen over a 144 kbit/s unstable connection doesn't need the same logotype compared to someone who accesses the site with an iPad with a 100 Mbps Wi-Fi?
5. The source code is now changed to point to the new logotype. Time to test. Test that the change was performed correctly, obviously, but also that it didn't break something. Things happen, and a difference in a few pixels between the old and the new logotype may completely break the layouts on some devices. And when you release a new logotype, you probably want the press to tell how great your logo is, not how broken is the home page of your website.
6. Seems like there was indeed a small issue with the layout on some devices. Developers are working to fix it, then the regression tests run once again.
7. The regression tests passed, so the change is then delivered to production, that is, actually deployed to the servers. Given that there are a few thousand of servers in the world for this website, it could take several days in order for the change to be on all of them. Since the marketing folks want the logotype to be shown on a given day to everyone, a feature toggle is used to keep the old logo displayed for now.
8. The feature toggle, however, enables the new logotype for the staff who works in the company (and who signed a non-disclosure agreement). One of the employees spots a problem: the colors of the logotype are all wrong when [protanomaly color correction](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151850?hl=en) is set in China. Time to fix that.
9. A few days ago, when you're confident that there would be no issues, marketing asks to turn the feature toggle on for everyone. Operations teams are monitoring how many devices downloaded the new logo, while marketing department monitors the impact in media.

So to answer your question, no, big companies don't ask developers to change the source code when breaking news arrive. If they did, they would:

1. Put themselves at operational risk. As a media company, in a case of a coronavirus outbreak, you want to inform the public, not trying to solve a regression a developer introduced a few minutes ago.
2. Be extremely slow. Regression testing takes hours, and you simply cannot afford waiting for hours in a case of an important event.